# Extending form validation functions

Tags: 7, forms

How do I pass additional values to #element_validate so they can be used for validation?

I'm using hook_form_alter() and Drupal 7.

```
//Example 1
function my_validation_function($form, &$form_state) {
    //Validation Code
}
```

I would like to use:

```
//Example 2
function my_validation_function($form, &$form_state, $additional_values) {
    //Validation Code with access to $additional_values
}
```

This works for example 1:

```
$form['field']['#element_validate'] = array('my_validation_function');
```

How do I pass `$additional_values` to example 2 using `$form['field']['#element_validate']`

Comment: If you provide a little more context of what you are looking to accomplish (any why), you will likely get some better answers.

Comment: All the values available to hook_form_alter will be available to validate function if i am not wrong. So I do not understand what kind of values you need to pass from hook_form_alter to validation function.

Comment: Modified the original question.  It's a syntax question more than a validation question really.  I'm just not sure how to pass additional variables to a callback using #element_validate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function where_ever_extra_data_originates_from() {
  $extra_data_to_pass_on_stored_here = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);
  $extra_data_to_pass_on_stored_here = $actual_extra_data
}

function my_validation_function($form, &$form_state) {
  //Here's our extra stuff now
  $extra_data = &drupal_static(where_ever_extra_data_originates_from);
}
```

Comment: This is a MUCH better answer :-)

Comment: Agreed, I too have learned a better way - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add whatever extra elements to the $form_state array in your alter function and read them out in the validate function, like so:

```
function my_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  $form_state['additional_value'] = 'the extra value';
  $form['#validate'][] = 'my_validation_function';
}

function my_validation_function($form, &$form_state) {
  //Validation Code
  $extra = $form_state['additional_value']
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't alter(add to) the number of parameters that are passed to a hook function. You could declare the variable that you want passed into the function as "global" -> [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) when you define it and again in the function which would give you access to the value.

Comment: Sorry, but I simply _must_ downvote an answer that advocates a global.